# Getting data from LocalHost

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have many school images on my localhost PC with images have names of the Campus_id of the school. But every school may have 1 or many images. Let's say that a school with id=20 has images like `20_1, 20_2, 20_3` ... and school with `id=23`, h an s image like `23_1` only. I want to get those images and show it using Angular and Html. What i did is to put the images in an array and show it using Ngfor. But the problem is that i do not know the number of the images in each school.

Here is how to iterate over all photos saved in data.attributes.photos, and generate a separate slide for each one.

Environment URL:

> resimUrl: 'http://localhost/mebresim/'

> data.attributes.photos = environment.resimUrl + data.attributes.kampus_id + '.jpg';

OR simply its like:

TypeScript:

> data.attributes.photos = [ "12.jpg", "12_1.jpg", "12_2.jpg" ]

HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel>
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photos">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [src]="photo" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Here getting and putting in array is working if you know that each school has constant number of images. But how about if i do not know the number of images a school has?

Comment: if you turn on server folder listings (normally not a recommended thing), you can scrape the landing with ajax and parse out all the <A> tags that have an href to an image. if you have access to the site source, you can write a shell script that generates a list of folder image counts.

Comment: I dont want to count all images. What i want is to show all images that starts with the name of school id and show it.

Comment: ahh, you have a full list in-hand. in that case, you can filter out the list before rendering, and that will give you the count as well.

Comment: Could you please tell me in detail what i should do before putting them in array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the images in the numerical order and continue when it fails.

```
 //This function will try to load an image and fire callbacks on the availablity.
 //Images are automatically cached at this point (bonus)
function testImage(url) {
    var tester=new Image();
    tester.onload=imageFound;
    tester.onerror=imageNotFound;
    tester.src=url;
}

function imageFound() {
   loadNext();    //Try the next one    
}

function imageNotFound() {
   //Last image loading failed. Proceed showing images you have got.
   console.log('Last Index: ' + lastIndex - 1;);

   //showImages();    
}


function loadNext(){

   testImage('http://localhost/mebresim/' + data.attributes.kampus_id + '_' + lastIndex);

   lastIndex++;
}

//Trigger image loading
var lastIndex = 0;
loadNext();
```

Comment: I could not integrated your code in my Angular typescript code. It gives many errors.

Comment: Copy and paste would not do.